# Why is BufferedReader readLine reading past EOF

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, eof

I have a very large file (~6GB) that has fixed-width text separated by \r\n, and so I'm using buffered reader to read line by line. This process can be interrupted or stopped and if it is, it uses a checkpoint "lastProcessedLineNbr" to fast forward to the correct place to resume reading. This is how the reader is initialized.

```
private void initializeBufferedReader(Integer lastProcessedLineNbr) throws IOException {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    if(lastProcessedLineNbr==null){lastProcessedLineNbr=0;}

    for(int i=0; i<lastProcessedLineNbr;i++){
        reader.readLine();
    }
    currentLineNumber = lastProcessedLineNbr;
}
```

This seems to work fine, and I read and process the data in this method:

```
public Object readItem() throws Exception {
    if((currentLine = reader.readLine())==null){
        return null;
    }
    currentLineNumber++;
    return parse(currentLine);
}
```

And again, everything works fine until I reach the last line in the document. readLine() in the latter method throws an error:

```
17:06:49,980 ERROR [org.jberet] (Batch Thread - 1) JBERET000007: Failed to run job ProdFileRead, parse, org.jberet.job.model.Chunk@3965dcc8: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:569)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:369)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:370)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.rational.batch.reader.TextLineReader.readItem(TextLineReader.java:55)
```

Curiously, it seems to be reading past the end of the file and allocating so much space that it runs out of memory. I tried looking at the contents of the file using Cygwin and "tail file.txt" and in the console it gave me the expected 10 lines. But when I did "tail file.txt > output.txt" output.txt ended up being like 1.8GB, much larger than the 10 lines I expected. So it seems Cygwin is doing the same thing. As far as I can tell there is no special EOF character. It's just the last byte of data and it ends abruptly.

Anyone have any idea on how I can get this working? I'm thinking I could resort to counting the number of bytes read until I get the full size of the file, but I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Of course, adding an EOF to the file myself also occurred to me, but I'm also not sure what is the java way to put an EOF character, since that's OS specific. I'd like it to work in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: There are no "EOF characters" on either Windows or Linux.  Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z are interpreted by the terminal I/O subsystem and signal EOF to the reading process.  Putting one of these in a file will not have the intended effect.  The real question is what is the contents of the file at the "last" record.  From the exception it appears the last "line" is very large, large enough to overflow available memory.  Are you _sure_ all lines are `\r\n` delimited?  Is there empty space allocated in the file _after_ the last line, that is being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I did `tail file.txt > output.txt` output.txt ended up being like 1.8GB, much larger than the 10 lines I expected

What this indicates to me is that the file is padded with 1.8GB of binary zeroes, which Cygwin's `tail` command ignored when writing to the terminal, but which Java is not ignoring.  This would explain your `OutOfMemoryError` as well, as the `BufferedReader` continued reading data looking for the next `\r\n`, never finding it before overflowing memory.

Comment: It was probably the terminal that ignored all the nulls.

Comment: @EJP you're right. I just checked the last 10000 bytes, they're all null. I just have a tendency to blame my programming logic than the input. A good lesson for me. lol. Thank you, both.